# wkhtmltopdf generates tiny output on Mac

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm running wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 on Mac OS 10.11.6. When I try to run the basic example "wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf", though, I'm getting an unusual output. Where I'm expecting something like this:

[image: Expected]

(PDF generated directly from Chrome), I'm instead getting this:

[image]

It seems odd to me that the default output should be so far off, but I've tried some options as well (including --disable-smart-shrinking) with no luck. Would appreciate any direction you can offer!

Comment: I get the same issue. I didn't find  solution yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, using wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.4 on a Mac installed via homebrew.  I uninstalled that and tried version 0.12.3, downloaded from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/, and now I have normal size output.

Answer (score 6):

Same here with Mac OS 10.11.6 WKHTMLTOPDF v 0.12.4.

Using `--lowquality` is the only thing that seems to resolve the "tiny output" issue.

Default wkhtmltopdf output without `--lowquality`:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cebqz.jpg)

With `--lowquality`, "tiny output" issue is fixed (and works with additional options like increasing resolution via --viewport-size):
[--lowquality screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRyQI.jpg)

Comment: This helped me too! Thanks! Never would have guessed that one.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to use the 0.12.4 version on Mac OS 10.13.3. 
Adding some information about this issue.

1. This is a known issue in 0.12.4 version. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3241
2. It has been fixed in a commit but not yet released as part of 0.12.4
   https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/commit/1c0e72d2faa6da026edc139fac97fcda43535fd3
3. the 'lowquality' flag fix discussed above is the fastest way to resolve this OR you can install the 0.12.5 version if you are an advanced user. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

To solve problem install `wkpdftohtml` via

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: No difference with this, even explicitly running /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: I have the same problem like you describe, and installing via bomebrew help me.  I thought that it also help you. I think you should try to install older version.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when running `wkhtmltopdf` on very large screens, and found that specifying *print media-type* instead of *screen media-type*, i.e. via `--print-media-type`, resolved the issue.

For example:

```
wkhtmltopdf --print-media-type http://google.com google.pdf
```

Comment: No luck with that here -- running the command as you give it generates the same output as above. It's working well on the Amazon EC2 instance where I need it to work, but still rendering tiny locally.

Comment: Have you tried combining `--print-media-type` with e.g. `--page-size letter`, specifying the page size?

Comment: I have -- still no luck, even with a fresh brew install.

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange. Perhaps open [an issue in the wkhtmltopdf repo](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues)?

Comment: Just noticed this issue: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3241 (Huge Font Size Difference Between 0.12.3 and 0.12.4) reported in `wkhtmltopdf` version `0.12.4`, could that be the cause here?