# Pandoc and html5 exporting pdf's with huge margins

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, pandoc

So I'm trying Pandoc for the first time. Everything seems great but when exporting via html5 (wkhtmltopdf) my pdf output is saved with huge margins on all sides.

```
pandoc -t html5 -s example.md -o output.pdf
```

[output.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNlhC.png) (content output highlighted in red)

What I've tried:

- Reinstalling pdflatex
- Reinstalling wkhtmltopdf
- Including CSS to remove the margins

Am I missing something?

**What I want:**
Write a markdown document using [Typora](https://typora.io/) -> Use Pandoc to apply TOC and page numbering -> Use html5 to export pdf with custom styling.

Comment: if you use `-t html`, you don't need `pdflatex`. so don't bother reinstalling it. to change the styling, modify your HTML template then: see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

Answer (score 13):

These pass through vars for `wkhtmltopdf` worked for me (ubuntu 18.10 pandoc 2.6) : https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-wkhtmltopdf

`pandoc -t html5 -V margin-top=3 -V margin-left=3 -V margin-right=3 -V margin-bottom=3 -V papersize=letter -s example.md -o output.pdf`

(Oddly `wkhtmltopdf` required all margins be the same.)

Comment: This worked (on my Mac.) But using `-V margins=0.75in`, for example, didn't. I needed all four options.

Comment: I was using a css file (with pandoc and wkhtmltopdf) and the css margins were having no effect until I set `-V margin-top=0` etc for all the margins.  Now I can set them all with CSS.

Comment: @alec setting margin only in CSS doesn't work for multiple pages, CSS is not aware of page breaks

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, the issue is caused by wkhtmltopdf (0.12.4) on macOS and supposedly Debian. I solved it by using only wkhtmltopdf (without Pandoc) and trying different parameters such as `--zoom` `--dpi` and `--disable-smart-shrinking`.

See:

[wkhtmltopdf generates tiny output on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814680/wkhtmltopdf-generates-)

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3241